# How to use NewsAPI in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, feed

I want to build a website and insert news articles.
I found a free newsAPI website and I got apikey as below:
https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=3329a36068a14512b9acb66f2b8f800a

I want to my website has a Live News and display some top news. but I don't know how to write proper code in Laravel. I have tried below code and only display image. I don't know how to display author, tile, description,url, etc. like newsAPI website live response. Appreciate if someone could help me.

```
 <?php

      $urlArticles = file_get_contents('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=3329a36068a14512b9acb66f2b8f800a');
      $urlArticlesArray = json_decode($urlArticles, true);

       $articles = $urlArticlesArray['articles'];
       for($i = 0; $i < count($articles); $i++) {
         $sites = $urlArticlesArray['articles'][$i];
         echo '<img src="'.$sites['urlToImage'].'">';

         }

       ?>
```

newsAPI website Live response example:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"source": "techcrunch",
"sortBy": "top",
-"articles": [
-{
"author": "Lucas Matney",
"title": "Gadgets",
"description": "Product reviews and demos from our TechCrunch Gadget team",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/video/gadgets/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/techcrunch-gadgets-icon_rect.png?w=450&h=200&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-04-07T23:00:45Z"
},
-{
"author": "Romain Dillet",
"title": "Uber is now banned in Italy for unfair competition",
"description": "While Uber is fighting Waymo at home, the American company is also having issues abroad. As Reuters reported, an Italian court has ordered Uber to stop all..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/09/uber-is-now-banned-in-italy-for-unfair-competition/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/uber.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-04-09T09:53:47Z"
},
-{
"author": "Ryan Lawler",
"title": "Gig economy stalwart TaskRabbit is contemplating a sale",
"description": "One of the earliest and most prominent startups of the so-called \"sharing economy\" or \"gig economy,\" is evaluating the possibility of selling itself. As..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/08/taskrabbit-acquisition-maybe/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/taskrabbit-fire.png?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-04-08T23:44:34Z"
},
-{
"author": "Ryan Lawler",
"title": "Netflix’s long-time chief product officer Neil Hunt is leaving the company",
"description": "Streaming video provider Netflix is making a change in its senior management, as the company announced long-time chief product officer Neil Hunt will be..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/08/netflix-neil-hunt-leaving/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/los-gatos_01.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-04-08T21:30:52Z"
},
-{
"author": "Natasha Lomas",
"title": "Postepic is an app for elegantly sharing book quotes",
"description": "Postepic wants to liberate all those interesting text snippets you have languishing on your camera roll and turn them into visually appealing quotations ready..",
"url": "https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/08/postepic-is-an-app-for-elegantly-sharing-book-quotes/",
"urlToImage": "https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/p1050418.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1",
"publishedAt": "2017-04-08T16:00:31Z"
}
]
}
```

Comment: If `$sites['urlToImage']` gets you the image, `$sites['author']` will get you the author, and so on. It's the same thing, just with different keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first: I would use something like Guzzle to call external sources....
[Guzzle Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org)

Then, in your code...

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://.....';
$response = $client->get(url);

dd($response->getStatusCode()); // will dump the statuscode
dd($response->getBody()); // will dump the body
$body = $response->getBody(); //assign body to var
```

etc...